# Force exponential power in yaxis with matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a two plots I want to show on the one figure. The data I'm using are in scientific format with different exponential powers. Can I get the plot to show the same exponential power? Bellow is my current minimal working example:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


xdata = np.array([1,2,3,4,5])

# Data Set 1
ydata1 = np.array([0.5e-11, 0.6e-11, 4.e-11, 5.e-11, 10.e-11])
ydata1err = np.array([1.e-11, 1.e-11, 1.e-11, 1.e-11, 1.e-11])

# Data Set 2
ydata2 = np.array([0.5e-11, 0.6e-11, 0.4e-11, 0.5e-11, 1.e-11])
ydata2err = np.array([0.5e-11, 0.5e-11, 0.5e-11, 0.5e-11, 0.5e-11])

# Creating Figure
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)    # The big subplot
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(211)
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(212)    

# Plotting Data
ax1.errorbar(xdata, ydata1, yerr=ydata1err, fmt='bo')
ax2.errorbar(xdata, ydata2, yerr=ydata2err, fmt='ro')
```

This plots two graphs with range [0,1.e-10] and [0,1.e-11]. What I would like is [0,1.e-10] and [0,0.1e-10].

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ax.set_ylim()` to limit the data for each subplot. If you want them to have the same limits you can do:

```
y_range = [0,1*10**-10]
ax1.errorbar(xdata, ydata1, yerr=ydata1err, fmt='bo')
ax1.set_ylim(y_range)
ax2.errorbar(xdata, ydata2, yerr=ydata2err, fmt='ro')  
ax2.set_ylim(y_range)
```

Comment: Hi Thanks what I'm trying to do is have different limits but have the same exponential power. so I'll have:

    ax1.set_ylim(0,1.e-10)
    ax2.set_ylim(0,0.1e-10)

This will however still give 0 - 1.e-11 on the y-axis what I want 0 - 0.1e-10. It's the same limit just a cosmetic difference.

Comment: Hi, sorry I must have miss-read your question. In that case, just replace `y_range` with the limits you want for each axis (ax1,ax2)

Comment: Additionally, if you want to set very specific points on the y axis, you can add `ax1.set_xticks(np.arange(1*10**-9,1*10**-11))` for example to control exactly what ticks are shown. If this is what you were looking for, I'll add it to my original answer.

Comment: Hi, thats not really what I'm looking for. I can set the range just fine what I want to do is to have upper range to be 0.1e-10 instead of 1e-11. This is the same range. I just want to display 0.1e-10 instead of 1.e-11.

Comment: Hi, in that case you can use something like `plt.yticks(values, labels)` where values represent the range of data you want to show and labels are a equally sized list of strings that will be shown. This way you can replace `1e-11` with `0.1e-10`. Hopefully this is what you are looking for!